# logback.xml is not creating log file while jar file is running

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, loggerfactory

I've got a little touble with creating log file. There is no problem when code is run from IntelliJ. In this case after few seconds log file appears and is being updated during code execution.

But when I create jar file and run it I can't see or even find in the hard drive any log created ...

Here's my logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>


<appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.err</target>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>TRACE</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>logs/log_engine.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | %-5p | [%thread] %logger{5}:%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>


<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

</root>
```

Comment: Is the logback.xml in the classpath when you run the jar?

Comment: When you run the jar file, try to specify a logback.xml file as a VM option? Like "-Dlogback.configurationFile=/x/y/z/logback.xml". If that works, you could be having a classpath problem.

Comment: @Luke I tried your idea, but still no log file :(